# Can't get the HOC pattern to work in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I was experimenting with HOC components but there seems to be some problem with how it's rendering in the browser. The HOC code is -

```
var HOC=(InnerComp)=> class extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return <InnerComp {...this.props} c="d"/>
  }
};
```

The problem is that the c="d" prop is not visible on the inner component when I use the HOC with a component such as this -

```
class MyTextArea extends React.Component{

render(){
      return (
          <textarea b="c"/>
      );
  }
}
var ControlledTA=HOC(MyTextArea);
```

Now if I use the ControlledTA component in my page, in the browser, if I do an inspect element, the textarea element only has the b="c" in its attributes and the c="d" is not present.

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <div><ControlledTA /></div>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

I can only get it to work if I write my inner component's render function like this -

```
render(){
    return (
          <textarea b="c" {...this.props} />
    );
}
```

which suggests that the inner component has to be aware that it needs to render some external properties that it will inherit, which seems bizarre.

Can anybody please confirm if this is how it's supposed to work, or if I'm doing anything wrong?

**Update**

For anyone looking for the right way to do this (according to the answer) - 
new inner component -

```
const MyInput=(props)=> {
   return (
       <div><input type="text" name="typeahead" value={props.data} onChange= 
             {props.onChange}/>
       </div>
   );
 }
```

new HOC -

```
function controlledForm(Mycomponent){
   return class extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={value:''};
        this.handleChange=this.handleChange.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(e){
        this.setState({value:e.target.value});
    }
    render(){
        return <Mycomponent {...this.props} data={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />;
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR** : 
The component is what carries the props, not the root HTML element.

`<textarea b="c"/>` would only have a prop of `b` because that is the only prop that you are passing to it.

The HOC is passing the prop to inner component which is `MyTextArea`, this component has the prop `c`.

This is also why it appears when you spread the props of `MyTextArea` using `this.props`.

From the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html):

> Note that a HOC doesn’t modify the input component, nor does it use
>   inheritance to copy its behavior. Rather, a HOC composes the original
>   component by wrapping it in a container component. A HOC is a pure
>   function with zero side-effects.
>
> And that’s it! The wrapped component receives all the props of the
>   container, along with a new prop, data, which it uses to render its
>   output. The HOC isn’t concerned with how or why the data is used, and
>   the wrapped component isn’t concerned with where the data came from.

```js
const HOC=(InnerComp)=> class extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return <InnerComp {...this.props} c="d"/>
  }
};

class MyTextArea extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    console.log("Props from Parent", this.props);
    return (
      <textarea a="b" defaultValue={"Props from Parent: "+ this.props.c}>
      </textarea>
    );
  }
}

const Enhanced = HOC(MyTextArea);


ReactDOM.render(<Enhanced />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: I understand that the props get passed on to MyTextArea, but I was under the impression that the React rendering engine would automatically render the upper level props/attributes to the inner component, as that seemed to be implicitly mentioned in the many HOC tutorials I read. Can you please confirm if this is indeed the way it's supposed to work? If yes, is there any other way to "pass on" these attributes without the inner component having to know that it's going to be enhanced?

Comment: @Perx The inner component does not need to know it is enhanced, it just needs to use the prop that it receives. React does not attach it to the upper level attributes (because what if it is not what requires the prop) React would not do that.